# Graphics problem (Dualhead MSI nVidia GeForce 660)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

The computer boots up fine, however after only a minute or so of running, the applications and icons begin glitching (large verticle bars of solid color or missing text, similar to what I'd call "missingNo"). The GUI itself is not effected.

Initially I did not have this problem and it only resulted in occasional freezing. I was even able to play some games for a short period of time, but now I cannot have the computer on for more than 2 minutes without this happening.The graphics card is mounted properly and receiving adequate ventilation so i don't think its an overheating issue.

I don't even have enough time to go to the nVidia site and update the drivers.